# Add two numbers in two tables and find the corresponding value in any table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find the corresponding volume for a sounding not in the table.  Ex:  Correct volume for 0.175 sounding:

[image: SO19078601 question example]

In table 01 I have take volume for `.17` - ie: `25.719`
In table 01 I have take volume for `.005` - ie: `0.568`
So I need to add these volumes - that is:  `26.287`

My answer should be given in any blank cell that I select: 26.287

I need your assistance only for Excel format.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible 'as is' but a lot easier with a slight rearrangement of the tables, so I have taken the liberty of switching C2:D11 to A15 and A15:B23 to C2.

Expecting the Table 1 value in F1 and the Table 2 value in H1, then:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F1,A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

in F2, drag across to H2. Then in G3 `=SUM(F2:H2)`, which can be referred to from almost anywhere (say `=G3`) to give you the result (here 26.287).

[image: SO19078601 example]

However, because the relationship is linear it may be easier to use a formula like so:

```
=100*(F1+H1)*1.1353+6.419
```